# MySQL Workbench columns tab deactivated

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to add a new table in MySQL Workbench but I can't because the columns tab is deactivated.

[image]

Do you have any idea of what's happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just throwing this out there because I have had some similar issues recently with Win7.  Try starting the application as "administrator" first.

Comment: I've tried it but it hasn't work :-( Did you do anything else?

Comment: are you logged in to mysql as root?

Comment: Well.. I'm logged in with another user, but it can read and write (I've created other tables with phpmyadmin)

Comment: try logging in as root (admin) just for grins.  Also, can you create this table using direct sql instead of using the admin console?

Comment: yes I can create it using sql directly. I only have this user because it is in a shared server (godaddy).

Comment: oh man, I have wasted hours using gogdaddy's crappy setup.  I usually resort to SSHing into the box and running it from the command line.  Not sure if you have this option but I might not waste too much more time on the console.

Comment: Hahaha thanks for your time and help, I really thought it was something I was doing bad way... I'm just doing this for a test and had many databases available in GoDaddy so I gave it a try ;-). Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply pull the whole lower tab a bit upwards and you'll see the bit where to enter your columns.

Comment: This was one of the simplest solutions I've seen here on SO. If you're here for this issue, you probably have a widescreen too. :)