# MySQL Workbench - Cannot add columns to a table

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a critical problem with MySQL Workbench: I actually cannot edit the "Columns" tab, because it is greyed out.

I tried to edit a table's columns both for a newly created diagram and for an existing diagram, but with no luck. Is there a bug in the last versions of WB, or am I missing something else?

I found this problem both with the WB version installed via the OS package management (apt) and with the version installed from source.

OS: debian jessie/sid

WB version (installed via APT): 6.1.7 build 1788 (6.1.7+dfsg-1)

WB version (installed from source): 6.2.3 build 2280

P.S. I have already readed a couple of similar questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671278/column-input-greyed-out-in-mysql-workbench) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414723/mysql-workbench-columns-tab-deactivated)), but they don't fit with my problem.

[image: Columns not editable]

Comment: Still not fixed in 6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to work before Debian updates it, I suggest you to download the mysql-workbench source, apply [this patch](http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=21874&bug_id=74147), build the package and then install it.

EDIT:

**Instructions**

As normal user, open a terminal and do the following:

```
cd ~
mkdir mysql-workbench-source
cd mysql-workbench-source
su root (type root password)
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install pbuilder
apt-get source mysql-workbench
apt-get build-dep mysql-workbench
cd mysql-workbench-6.1.7+dfsg/frontend/linux/linux_utilities
cp ~/Downloads/glib.diff . (don't forget the last dot).
patch <glib.diff
cd ~/mysql-workbench-6.1.7+dfsg
debuild -us -uc -b (this will take a while)
cd ..
dpkg -i mysql-workbench_6.1.7+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i mysql-workbench-data_6.1.7+dfsg-1_all.deb
```

It should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes, it was fixed by the next version of the mysql-workbench package.

Answer (score 2):

If it's like my problem was - I created a table and I couldn't add columns - there was a panel over the editable area. Maximize the window, and it should become visible.

Comment: In my case it was a problem on the Linux platform.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem on the linux platform which needs to be addressed by the dev team. The best way to have this fixed quickly is to create a bug report on http://bugs.mysql.com. Give it a high severity.